# Reducing $9\times9$ determinant to $3\times3$ determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Consider the $9\times 9$ matrix

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} i e_3 \times{} & i & 0 \\ 
-i & 0 & -a \times{} \\
0 & a \times{} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

for some vector $a \in \mathbb R^3$, where $\times$ is the cross product.

It is claimed in [Fu and Qin - Topological phases and bulk-edge correspondence of magnetized cold plasmas](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-021-24189-3) that this can be reduced to the determinant of a $3\times3$ matrix, meaning

$$ \det(M-\omega ) = \det(N_1-N_2+N_3)=0.$$

Here

$$N_1 = \frac{aa^t}{\omega^2}, N_2 =\frac{a^ta}{\omega^2}\operatorname{id},\text{ and }N_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1-\frac{1}{\omega^2-1} & i\frac{1}{\omega(\omega^2-1)} & 0 \\ -i\frac{1}{\omega(\omega^2-1)} &1-\frac{1}{\omega^2-1} & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 1-\frac{1}{\omega^2}  \end{pmatrix}.$$

This determinant is stated as equation (1) versus the original $9\times9$ matrix is equation (11).

How can we derive the determinant of the $3\times 3$ matrix from the determinant of the $9\times 9 $ matrix without first expanding the determinant?

Comment: Is $i$ the imaginary unit here? And $e_3$ is the vector [0,0,1], and $i$ alone in a block means $i$ times the $3\times 3$ identity matrix, right?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni indeed.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker really, what is the difference? - Of course I put all constants apart from omega and k equal to one.

Comment: OK, if it's the same equation I am at a loss to explain why I cannot make it work (even for the simple case $a=(1,0,0)$).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker and I believe in your computation. But I am still curious if there is an obvious way to reduce this 9x9 determinant to a 3x3 determinant using some symmetries of the original block matrix?

Comment: OK, with some further effort I found the error in your post; your definitions of $N_1$ and $N_2$ should be multiplied by $1/\omega$.  Then it works out, see the answer below.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest way to reduce $$A=M-\omega I$$ to a $3\times 3$ matrix is to use the Schur complement with respect to the $(\bar 2,\bar 2)$-elements of $A$,
\begin{align}
C = A/A_{\bar 2,\bar 2} = A_{2,2} - A_{2,\bar 2} A_{\bar 2,\bar 2}^{-1} A_{\bar 2,2}.
\end{align}
Here, $\bar 2$ denotes the index complement of $2$, i.e., $\bar 2\equiv\{1,3\}$. We get
\begin{align}
C = -\omega(N_1 - N_2 + N_3).
\end{align}
With
\begin{align}
\det A_{\bar 2,\bar 2}=\omega^4(\omega^2-1)
\end{align}
and $\det A=\det A_{\bar 2,\bar 2}\det C$ the result follows.

@Carlo: Thanks for posting the MMA notebook! Note that there is a small mistake in the definition of $N_3$, which needs to be transposed.

Comment: thanks for catching the missing transpose (which of course does not change the determinant)

Answer (score 6):

The formula's in the OP contain an error: the $\omega$ in the denominator of $N_1$ and $N_2$ should be $\omega^2$, so
$$N_1 = \frac{aa^t}{\omega^2}, N_2 =\frac{a^ta}{\omega^2}\operatorname{id}.$$
Then it works out:

$${\rm det}\,(M-\omega)=-\omega^9+2 \omega^7 \left(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+2\right)-\omega^5 \left(a_1^4+2 a_1^2 \left(a_2^2+a_3^2+3\right)+\left(a_2^2+a_3^2\right)^2+6 a_2^2+6 a_3^2+4\right)+\omega^3 \left(2 a_1^4+a_1^2 \left(4 a_2^2+4 a_3^2+3\right)+2 \left(a_2^2+a_3^2\right)^2+3 a_2^2+4 a_3^2+1\right)-\omega a_3^2  \left(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2\right)$$
$$=\omega^7 \left(1-\omega^2\right)\,{\rm det}\,(N_1-N_2+N_3).$$

[Link](https://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/determinant_check.nb) to the Mathematica notebook.

Comment: thanks a lot for your work. I guess then the better question is probably, how to reduce this 9x9 matrix to a 3x3 matrix...

Comment: Well, I think the Hamiltonian is still correct, no? - And I think the fact that these guys reduced it to a 3x3 matrix meant that there is an obvious symmetry to exploit.-After all, every block is 3x3...

Comment: I identified the error in your post and revised the Mathematica notebook with the correct expressions for $N_1$ and $N_2$. The determinants now agree.

Comment: I get a little lost in the notation.  Wasn't the original claim about $\det(M - \omega)$, not about $\det(M)$?  Also, is there any conceptual reason why one should expect an identity of this sort, or is it just luck that one can but verify *a posteriori*?

Comment: certainly, $\det(M-\omega)$ --- the matrix $M$ itself is $\omega$-independent, thanks for noting this; the authors of the paper give no clue, who knows, it may be possible to verify this without explicit computation, this is the best I can do.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thanks for finding the typo.